# Rails MySQL cannot single mass insert

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

this is my create method in controller:

```
def create
    @promo = current_user.promos.build(promo_params)

    if @promo.save
      inserts = []
      params[:user_limit].to_i.times do
        inserts.push "(#{@promo.id}, #{SecureRandom.hex(3).upcase})"
      end
      sql = "INSERT INTO vouchers ('promo_id', 'promo_code') VALUES #{inserts.join(", ")}"
      ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)

      redirect_to provider_promo_path(@promo), notice: 'Promo was successfully created.'
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
```

My Voucher table schema :

```
class Voucher < ActiveRecord::Base {
            :id => :integer,
      :promo_id => :integer,
    :promo_code => :string,
         :email => :string,
        :status => :integer,
       :user_id => :integer,
    :created_at => :datetime,
    :updated_at => :datetime
}
```

in above controller method I only want to fill the `promo_id` and `promo_code` field. Does it cause the error? Here is the error message return:

```
Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''promo_id', 'promo_code') VALUES' at line 1: INSERT INTO vouchers ('promo_id', 'promo_code') VALUES
```

pointing to this line:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
```

Any suggest? thanks

**UPDATE**

I have edit my code:

```
inserts.push "(#{@promo.id}, '#{SecureRandom.hex(3).upcase}')"
```

But I have another error which is says:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Provider::PromosController#create
Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''promo_id', 'promo_code') VALUES (20, 'C23E37'), (20, '2A70D0'), (20, '6557DC')' at line 1: INSERT INTO vouchers ('promo_id', 'promo_code') VALUES (20, 'C23E37'), (20, '2A70D0'), (20, '6557DC')
```

the `sql` variable value is:

```
"INSERT INTO vouchers ('promo_id', 'promo_code') VALUES (21, '0D8D52'), (21, '1F6E58'), (21, 'C049DC')"
```

why it still error?

Comment: Check the sql query which is formed, there is a syntax error in the query

Comment: Please see my updated question

Comment: SQL-Injection: never write the user given parameters directly in the Sting.

Comment: @Meier, you're right, but in this case SQL-injection is not possible. `@promo.id` will always be an integer and `SecureRandom.hex(3).upcase` is not user input.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
inserts.push "(#{@promo.id}, #{SecureRandom.hex(3).upcase})"
```

should be:

```
inserts.push "(#{@promo.id}, '#{SecureRandom.hex(3).upcase}')"
```

`SecureRandom.hex(3).upcase` is a string, so it should be in quotes in your query.

Also, this is wrong:

```
INSERT INTO vouchers ('promo_id', 'promo_code')
```

It should be:

```
INSERT INTO vouchers (`promo_id`, `promo_code`)
```

You can't use quotes around column names in MySQL.

Comment: Hi thanks, I forgot that one. Please see my updated questions

Comment: @KrisMP You should remove the quotes or replace them with backticks (`\``) in this section: `INSERT INTO vouchers ('promo_id', 'promo_code')`. You can't use quotes around column names in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing it another way.

Build an array of hashes for all your records:

```
inserts = []
params[:user_limit].to_i.times do
  record = {}
  record['promo_id'] = @promo.id
  record['promo_code'] = "#{SecureRandom.hex(3).upcase}"
  inserts << record
end
```

And, then create the vouchers:

```
Voucher.create(inserts)
```